# Command Line Mac: Configuring virtualenv

Tags: python, command-line, installation, osx-snow-leopard, virtualenv

I'm trying to set up virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on my mac. I have read around and tried to add it to my pythonpath, but still cannot use the command `mkvirtualenv`

Here is where I am:

```
admins-macbook:~ Admin$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
admins-macbook:~ Admin$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
admins-macbook:~ Admin$ export echo $PATH
-bash: export: `/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin': not a valid identifier

admins-macbook:~ Admin$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
admins-macbook:~ Admin$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv:$PATH
admins-macbook:~ Admin$ mkvirtualenv virtual
-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

How can I get virtualenv to work on my Mac? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Are you sure you installed `virtualenvwrapper`? It's a different project from `virtualenv` itself, and `mkvirtualenv` won't work without it - you would just do `virtualenv virtual`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Any idea why trying to run brew install virtualenvwrapper gives an error: `Error: No available formula for virtualenvwrapper`  Thanks for any ideas

Comment: virtualenvwrapper is pip installable: pip install virtualenvwrapper